# I Want to Use "Parse Notification" in my Android App

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I have an Android app published in the Google Play Store and I want to add Push notification.
I tried [Parse.com](http://www.parse.com) and I Implemented the code mentioned in [this guide](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/iOS).
When I tried to send a test push, Parse.com says: `No clients have subscribed to the broadcast push channel. Please double check that you've setup the SDK correctly.

Also, when I go to the parse cloud

**DASHBOARD --> Push Notifications --> Send A Push**

Parse says:
`Your application does not have any registered devices to which it can send notifications.`

I'm sure that I've implemented ALL the code correctly!

Comment: Can you include examples of how you've implemented Parse Push in your app?

Comment: Did you release the updated version of your app that included `push`?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you forgot (as the error message say tell you) to sign up with the device!

```
  ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
    user.setUsername("jondoe");
    user.setPassword("123456");
    user.setEmail("jon@gmail.com");


    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
      public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
          // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
        } else {
          // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
          // to figure out what went wrong
        }
      }

    @Override
    public void done(com.parse.ParseException arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
    });
```

After you device is registred the system knows to whom send notification!
Also, in your Parse.com dashboard in the tab "Data browser" you must see a row if you click "installation" on the left.